# Error in software unit testing simple program?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

Testcode.py

```
import code
import unittest

class TestCode( unittest.TestCase ):
    def test_simple( self ):
        self.assertEqual( code.return_zero(),0 )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

code.py

```
def return_zero ():
    return 0
```

expected ok result

but getting this below error

```
-----------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:++++++/.spyder-py3/testcode.py", line 6, in test_simple
    self.assertEqual( code.return_zero(),0 )
AttributeError: 'Testcode' object has no attribute 'assertnotEqual'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how your code has output this error.

you need to import the `return_code` from the `code` module.

from:

```
import code
```

to:

```
from code import return_code
```

or:

```
from code import *
```

and then:

```
self.assertEqual(return_zero(),0 )
```